# Pandas is not reading values from cells with formulas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a script that reads a column of cells and updates another one if the values on each cell have a specific value.

This is the script:

```
    statusclientes = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name="MONITORAMENTO", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "V")
    telclientes = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name="MONITORAMENTO", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "AF")
    marcacoes = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name="MONITORAMENTO", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols ="AN")
    nomedosclientes = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name="MONITORAMENTO", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols ="B")
    print(marcacoes)
    print(statusclientes)
    x=0
    while x < len(statusclientes):
        if (statusclientes.iloc[x][0] == "Offline"):
            p=marcacoes.iloc[x][0]
            p=p+1
            marcacoes.iat[x,0]= p
            print(nomedosclientes.iloc[x,0])
            tel_off.append(telclientes.iloc[x][0])
        if (statusclientes.iloc[x][0] == "Online"):
            marcacoes.iat[x,0]= 0
        x=x+1
```

The problem with this script is that it can't read cells with formulas - instead of reading their values, it reads as "NaN" (which is currently happening with the dataframe "statusclientes").

I've researched and apparently this is not the usual behavior of pandas, so, what is possibly going wrong ?

EDIT:

1- Here goes the formula inside the cell that can't be read:

```
=SEERRO(SE(F682="Não"; "Indefinido";SE(G682="Fronius";PROCV(B682;'DADOS SOLARWEB'!$B$2:$G$999;5;FALSO);SE(W682<>"N/A";SE(X682<>"--";SE(DATADIF(W682;$A$3;"d")=0;"Online";"Offline");"Indefinido");"Offline")));"Indefinido")
```

2- Here's how the dataframe is:

```
[685 rows x 1 columns]
    Unnamed: 21
0           NaN
1           NaN
2        Status
3           Nan
4           NaN
..          ...
680         NaN
681         NaN
682         NaN
683         NaN
684         NaN
```

"status" is a text cell, every cell bellow "status" has the formula pointed above. besides that, I can't think of anything else worth mentioning. The sheet has macros, but removing it doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is how the cells looks like:

[image]

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

SOMETHING else that is important is that this sheet is downloaded from a drive everytime the code runs, and then it's uploaded there when the code finishes. This may be important because whenever I manually save the sheet on the drive, this code works fine, if it was just uploaded by the code itself and I try to run the code again, then this happens, does anyone know why ?

Since it was asked,here's the code I use to download and then update the file on the drive

```
def download(self):
    
    SCOPES='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'H:\Meu Drive\DriveAPI\key.json', SCOPES)
    
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
    request=service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.FileIO('test.xlsm', mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))


def updatar(self):
    """Inicializa a instância do google drive
        Essa função pode retornar a instância como um objeto para a classe, ou pode realizar a operação direto sempre que a instância é iniciada
    """
    
    SCOPES='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        '.\key.json', SCOPES)

    # Builda o objeto service
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    #Essa parte vai definir os parametros do request à api do drive
    file_metadata = {'name': 'test.xlsm','parents':['insert here your parent folder']}
    file_name='test.xlsm'
    mime_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    media = MediaFileUpload('./{0}'.format(file_name),mimetype=mime_type)
    #updata o arquivo no drive
    file = service.files().update(media_body=media,
                                        addParents='insert here your parent folder',
                                        fileId=file_id).execute()
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of the forumlas (and results) which are reading as `NaN`?

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What does the excel file look like, and what does the DataFrame look like after pandas reads it in? Can you attach this information in the question?

Comment: Also, I believe the parameter `na_values=['NA']` is redundant, as pandas includes this to read as `NaN` by default.

Comment: I will add those infos !

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm pretty sure Pandas can't execute the formulas

Comment: But wasn't it supposed to read the value given by the cell ? I'll post what the cell looks like

Comment: SOMETHING else that is important is that this sheet is downloaded from a drive everytime the code runs, and then it's uploaded there when the code finishes. This may be important because whenever I manually save the sheet on the drive, this code works fine, if it was just uploaded by the code itself and I try to run the code again, then this happens, does anyone know why ?

Comment: Can you share some minimal code to reproduce the issue you are having?

Comment: I posted it, but I don't know if it's going to be of any help

Comment: You can use the drive code combined with the other instances and reproduce what I am doing easily

Comment: My best guess is that the file is "losing" the calculated values when you download, which might have something to do with downloading it in binary mode? You might be able to check by downloading a file with your code, and opening it in Excel with calculation mode set to manual.

Comment: I can open the file download by code and it works just fine, but I actually agree with you in part. Maybe pandas can't read the file because it is uploaded in a specific way (and the problem is most definetelly on uploading, since the code always works on the first time it runs, i.e. when it downloads for the first time)